# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::only()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4.2 framework php. I want to retrieve the id where the username will be equal to what I want to find. I want to find username's id basically. I'm use only method, to retrieve 'id' but didn't work. It tells me method not working. Perhaps I has different version of :aravel version.

```
$user_id = User::where('username','=',$username)->only('id');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use `->pluck('id')` instead of `->only('id')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `->only()` works in this situation. Try:

```
User::select("id")->where("username", "=", $username)->first();
```

You can use `->first()` to get one record or `->get()` to get all that match.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an Eloquent model, the `id` property is already there in the retrieved result object. Even saving it to a variable is probably unnecessary.

```
User::where('username', '=', $username)->first()->id
```